# python: How can I press arrow keys randomly selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, random, while-loop, automated-tests

I am trying to make a program which plays [2048](https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) by randomly choosing arrow keys.

I tried something like this:

```
 moves = [htmlElem.send_keys(Keys.UP),htmlElem.send_keys(Keys.RIGHT),htmlElem.send_keys(Keys.DOWN),htmlElem.send_keys(Keys.LEFT)]


while True:
    random.choice(moves)
```

This is not working. I tried `print(random.choice(moves))`, but it infinite loop of `None`

So how can I press arrows keys randomly using Selenium?

Comment: try using `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys element = driver.find_element_by_id("Value")
element.send_keys("keysToSend")
element.submit()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seem to work. Try it and let me know the result:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import random

moves = [Keys.LEFT, Keys.DOWN, Keys.RIGHT, Keys.UP]
while True:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(random.choice(moves))
```

Comment: It works I changes `moves = [Keys.LEFT, Keys.DOWN, Keys.RIGHT, Keys.UP]` and `htmlElem.send_keys(random.choice(moves))`