# Send Keys to Game Container 2048

Tags: python, html, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to send keys to 2048, and I am trying to wait until the game container element is located and then send keys to it. For some reason selenium can't locate the game container. I am assuming this has some issue to do with focusing on the right element, but I can't figure it out.

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, r'/html/body/div[1]/div[4]'))).send_keys(Keys.UP)
```

This raises a timeout exception because it cannot locate the game container.
Can someone help me with sending arrow keys to 2048? I'm on https://play2048.co/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import random
import time

moves = [Keys.LEFT, Keys.DOWN, Keys.RIGHT, Keys.UP]
while True:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').send_keys(random.choice(moves))
    time.sleep(2)
```

[python: How can I press arrow keys randomly selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42060724/python-how-can-i-press-arrow-keys-randomly-selenium)

Comment: Infinite chad god bless!